# Use different ColorFunction for each function plotted

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

When plotting two curves on one plot, you can specify different colors for each function:

```
Plot[{Sin@x, Cos@x}, {x, 0, 4π},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To plot the curves using different `ColorFunction`s, you can manually combine the plots:

```
Show[
 Plot[Sin@x, {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]},
  ColorFunction -> ({x, y} \[Function] Opacity[y, Red])],
 Plot[Cos@x, {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]},
  ColorFunction -> ({x, y} \[Function] Opacity[y, Blue])]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But if you try to combine them into one `Plot[]` expression, it doesn't work:

```
Plot[{Sin@x, Cos@x}, {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]},
 ColorFunction -> {({x, y} \[Function] 
     Opacity[y, Red]), ({x, y} \[Function] Opacity[y, Blue])}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How can you easily plot multiple curves, specifying the `ColorFunction` to use for each?

Comment: I hate to say it, but the only way is the method using `Show`. You could combine it with `MapThread` to reduce the amount of typing, but that's about it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To my knowledge, as soon as you specify a `ColorFunction`, every point `{x,y}` no matter to which function it belongs is colorized by the same function.

If you want to achieve this behavior without modifying built-in functions, you could use the `UpValues` of an arbitrary symbol, for instance `MultiColorFunction`. With this, you specify how a plot-command has to be divided into several calls which are then combined with `Show`. Luckily, we have to do this only once for all plot-commands (I use here only `Plot` and `Plot3D`)

```
MultiColorFunction /: (h : (Plot | Plot3D))[{fs__}, before___,
   MultiColorFunction[cf__], after___] := 
 Show[h[#1, before, ColorFunction -> #2, after] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{{fs}, {cf}}]]
```

Now you can simply call

```
Plot[{Sin@x, Cos@x}, {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, 
  MultiColorFunction["Rainbow", "Pastel"], PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and it works similar for `Plot3D`

```
Plot3D[{Sin[x y], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
 MultiColorFunction[Function[{x, y, z}, RGBColor[x, y, 0.]], "Pastel"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Further notes

Someone might say that when this works, why don't we use `TagSet` to make it possible to input this as e.g.

```
Plot[{Sin@x, Cos@x}, {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, MultiColorFunction -> {"Rainbow", "Pastel"}]
```

*without* actually defining a new option `MultiColorFunction`. The reason is simple, `TagSet` only works when the symbol we want to set is in the outer two levels. Therefore, while this

```
g /: f[g[h[x]]] := "blub"
```

works, this

```
h /: f[g[h[x]]] := "blub"
```

is not possible. Our `Plot` construct would have the form

```
Plot[....,Rule[MultiColorFunction,...],..]
```

so it would be equivalent to `h` of the example. There is of course an alternative. The last reachable level is the one of `Rule` but we don't want to change a built-in function. But what, if we don't use the normal `Rule` but a symbol which only looks like a rule-arrow? Let's try it. A quick check brings up `\[RightArrow]` which has no built-in meaning and looks perfect. Do you see the difference?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can input this arrow with <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> and it gets automatically transformed into `RightArrow[x,y]`.

```
RightArrow /: (h : (Plot | Plot3D))[{fs__}, before___,
     RightArrow[ColorFunction, {cf__}], after___] := 
  Show[h[#1, before, ColorFunction -> #2, after] & @@@ 
      Transpose[{{fs}, {cf}}]]

Plot[{Sin@x, Cos@x}, {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, 
  ColorFunction\[RightArrow]{"Rainbow", "Pastel"}, PlotStyle ->Thick]
```

Comment: This seems to mess with `PlotLegends`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Figured it out. `SwatchLegend` works just fine.

Answer (score 6):

I do not think this is possible. What happens is that both functions, in your case `Sin` and `Cos` will use the same `ColorFunction` and there is no way inside the `ColorFunction` to know which one is being called for at each time. (Unless your functions have some specific boundaries to them, that you check for inside the `ColorFunction`).

I did this little experiment to show this. 2 small lists `listA` and `listB`, one has 3 points, and one has 2 points. Then used `ListPlot` and used `ColorFunction`.  By changing the numbers of points, and the values, one would see that `ColorFunction` is being called for each function, one by one.

Inside the `ColorFunction` a counter is used, and the point is printed. One can see that the `listA` is processed, followed by the 'listB`, in order. i.e for each point,`ColorFunction` is evaluated. It does not matter if the point is coming from the first or the second list.

```
i = 0;
listA =  {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}};
listB =  {{0, 0}, {1, 1}};

ListPlot[{listA, listB},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, i++; Print[{i, x, y}]]
 ]
```

this prints

[image]

(The actual values do not match the values in the lists, due to scaling. These are coordinates into the plot window itself). But the point is, unless you know more information about each function, I do not see how to you can do what you want.

If you do know the number of points being used by each function to plot it, then you can add an `If` statement inside the `ColorFunction` to use different color based on this test.

As follows

```
i = 0;
listA = Table[RandomReal[], {100}];
listB = Table[RandomReal[], {30}];

ListPlot[{listA, listB},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[++i <= Length[listA], Red, Blue]]
 ]
```

The above would require you knowing this information. This was easy for `ListPlot` since one knows how many points there are for each list. For non-discrete functions like `Sin` and `Cos` in your example, you'd have to first sample them yourself, then find the length of the lists generated, then use the above trick, as follows

```
sin = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 4 Pi, .01}];
cos = Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 4 Pi, .01}];
i = 0;

ListLinePlot[{sin, cos},

 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y},
   If[ ++i <= Length[sin], 
       Opacity[y, Red], 
       Opacity[y, Blue]
      ] 
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A dirty hack that works quite well is the following:

```
Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, -1, 1}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[Abs[y - f1[x]] < 10^-3, Blue, Red]]]
```

and you can replace Blue and Red with the ColorFunction for the first and second function, respectively.