# Increasing the thickness of minimum of two curves while keeping their coloring the same

Tags: plotting

Let's say I am plotting

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.01], Thickness[0.01]}]
```

I want to keep the same colors for the two functions — $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ — but want to increase the thickness of the minimum of two functions for each value of $x$. What is the easiest way to do that?

#### Edit

I want to clarify what I meant. Let's say the colors of the two functions `f1` and `f2` are blue and red and thickness for both functions is 0.01. Now for each x, I just want to increase the thickness of the function $min(f1, f2)$ in the same plot while keeping the blue and red colors separately for `f1` and `f2`.

Comment: Do you mean you want varying thickness along the curve, depending on which curve is on top?

Comment: Thies, yes, exactly.

Comment: You could either achieve this by calling `Plot[{Min[f1[x],f2[x]],Max[f1[x],f2[x]]}]` and giving it different PlotStyles or by cutting the curves in segments where they cross and giving them individual PlotStyles.

Comment: Related: [(1128)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1128/121), [(8199)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8199/121), [(47967)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47967/125)

Comment: possible duplicate: [Plot the minimum of a list of functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47967/125)

Comment: @kglr Oh, that's another good related one, but I don't think it's a direct solution to this one?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47979/125) in the linked q/a works for this case too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for.

```
minSin[x_] /; Sin[x] < Cos[x] := Sin[x]
minCos[x_] /; Sin[x] > Cos[x] := Cos[x]
maxSin[x_] /; Sin[x] > Cos[x] := Sin[x]
maxCos[x_] /; Sin[x] < Cos[x] := Cos[x]

Plot[{minSin[x], maxSin[x], minCos[x], maxCos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π},
  PlotStyle ->
    {{Blue, Thickness[0.02]}, {Blue, Thickness[0.01]},
     {Red, Thickness[0.02]}, {Red, Thickness[0.01]}}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 9):

Choose two colors:

```
{c1,c2}={ColorData[97, 1], ColorData[97, 2]}
```

Define a custom color function:

```
myColorFunction[x_] := If[Cos[x] > Sin[x], c1,c2]
```

Generate two plots (because [you can't specify two different color functions in the same plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16262/use-different-colorfunction-for-each-function-plotted)) and combine them:

```
g1 = Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {c1,c2}];
g2 = Plot[Min[Sin[x], Cos[x]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.015], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   ColorFunction -> (myColorFunction[#1] &), Exclusions -> None];
Show[g2, g1, PlotRange -> {-1,1}]
```

Voilà:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

One way of doing this which works in this case would be:

```
Plot[Evaluate[MinMax[{#1, #2}]], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.01], Thickness[0.02]}, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData[97][1 + Boole[Sin[#1] == #2]] &)
] &[Sin[x], Cos[x]]
```

[image: Plot with two curves with varying thickness]

Comment: I think this doesn't answer the OP's question - the intention was to keep the colors but vary the thickness.

Comment: Fixed my answer.

Comment: That's very nice.

Answer (score 7):

Modifying [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47979/125) slightly:

```
flist = {Sin[x], Cos[x]};
pieces = Table[ConditionalExpression[f, f == Min[flist]], {f, flist}];
pltstyls = Join[#, Directive[{#, Thickness[.007]}] & /@ #] &[
  ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[;; Length@flist]]];

Plot[Evaluate@Join[flist, pieces], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> pltstyls]
```

[image]

More generally, for  arbitrary number of functions and filling:

```
flist = {Sin[x], Cos[x], x Sin[x]/2};
filling = Thread[Range[Length@flist] -> Axis];
pieces = Table[ConditionalExpression[f, f == Min[flist]], {f, flist}];
pltstyls = Join[#, Directive[{#, Thickness[.007]}] & /@ #] &[
  ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[;; Length@flist]]];

Plot[Evaluate@Join[flist, pieces], {x, 0, 10}, Filling -> filling, PlotStyle -> pltstyls]
```

[image]

Comment: I think the filling and the third line obfuscate this somewhat, but +1 nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard.

Answer (score 2):

Applying a modification of my own method from [Plot the minimum of a list of functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47967/121), and perhaps proving kglr's assertion that this question is a duplicate:

```
emph[fn_][a__] := Riffle[{a}, If[# == fn[a], #] & /@ {a}]

Plot[emph[Min][Sin[x], Cos[x]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}
 , Evaluated -> True
 , PlotStyle -> Tuples[{{Blue, Red}, AbsoluteThickness /@ {2, 4}}]
]
```

[image]